# Split Excel sheet into multiple workbooks based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have a spreadsheet with three columns, with column A having duplicate values. The row headers are in row 3. I'd like to split the sheet for each unique value in column A and its associated rows, where they're copied over to different workbooks - one workbook per unique value from column A.

I've been using the code below based on something I found online, however it seems very temperamental. Sometimes it works, but other times I get the error "Run-time error '1004': No cells were found." I've indicated the row in the code below with a comment where the debugger states the error is. Can someone please help me troubleshoot the code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ParseItems()
'Based on selected column, data is filtered to individual workbooks
'workbooks are named for the value plus today's date
Dim LR As Long, Itm As Long, MyCount As Long, vCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, MyArr As Variant, vTitles As String, SvPath As String

'Sheet with data in it
   Set ws = Sheets("input data")

'Path to save files into, remember the final \
    SvPath = "C:\My Work Documents\"

'Range where titles are across top of data, as string, data MUST
'have titles in this row, edit to suit your titles locale
    vTitles = "A1:AT1"

'Choose column to evaluate from, column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
   vCol = 1

'Spot bottom row of data
   LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vCol).End(xlUp).Row

'Speed up macro execution
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get a temporary list of unique values from key column
    ws.Columns(vCol).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws.Range("EE1"), Unique:=True

'Sort the temporary list
    ws.Columns("EE:EE").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("EE2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
       OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'(THIS IS WHERE THE DEBUGGER STOPS) Put list into an array for looping (values cannot be the result of formulas, must be constants)
    MyArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("EE2:EE" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

'clear temporary worksheet list
    ws.Range("EE:EE").Clear

'Turn on the autofilter, one column only is all that is needed
    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter

'Loop through list one value at a time
    For Itm = 1 To UBound(MyArr)
        ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=MyArr(Itm)

        ws.Range("A1:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Cells.Columns.AutoFit
        MyCount = MyCount + Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SvPath & MyArr(Itm) & Format(Date, " MM-DD-YY"), xlNormal
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SvPath & MyArr(Itm) & Format(Date, " MM-DD-YY") & ".xlsx", 51   'use for Excel 2007+
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol
    Next Itm

'Cleanup
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    MsgBox "Rows with data: " & (LR - 1) & vbLf & "Rows copied to other sheets: " & MyCount & vbLf & "Hope they match!!"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify - the error usually happens when I try to run the code again. To help me understand the code better, I'm trying to work out what triggers that error?